# How to make Visual Studio 2010 recognize file extensions as C#/ASPX/C/C++ files?

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio

There was a solution for VS 2005 here:

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/vs/3298/Make-Visual-C-recognize-file-extensions-as-C-files

But doesn't find same registry for VS2008 and VS2010. So where can I find the solution update for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If what you're looking for is syntax highlighting for different extensions in the VS 2010 editor: Go to Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> File Extensions and enter the extension.

Comment: I found this http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/ but it doesn't work. But yours works thanks a lot !

Comment: For example, to add file extension '.m' so that Visual Studio will recognize Macintosh XCODE iOS C files, type 'm' into Extension file, field "Editor:" = Microsoft Visual C++, and press "Add", close and re-open your .m file (if already open in VS), and there it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is any different.  You however have to change the version number in the registry key name HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Languages\File
Extensions.  VS2008 is 9.0, VS2010 is 10.0

These kind of registry hacks don't scale very well.  It stops working when you open the project on another machine or use a different VS version.  As you found out.  Just renaming the file is the much lower pain-point.

Comment: The same can be said about nearly any customization - key bindings, colorization, etc.  Export and import of these have improved immensely in recent VS versions, but I still find trying to keep all these consistent across installs and machines to be a pain.  But I think that's at least part of the nature of customizations (since they aren't the default behavior).

Comment: I have already looked at the registry it's not the same at all: there is no Language key under 8.0 or 10

Comment: There is on mine.  Beware of a 64-bit operating system.  The 32-bit keys are stored in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node