# Visual Studio 2015 - Associate custom file extension with cshtml editor

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, razorengine

I have a file with custom extension which contains Razor Syntax. I would like open this file as `cshtml` to see highlighted Razor Syntax.

What kind of editor should I associate in `Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extension` with my custom extension?
I've already tried all editors from the combobox but without success.
When I change the extension to `cshtml` then Razor Syntax is highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like this may not be possible - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890633/3682967).

Personally, I'm using the RazorEngine to generate HTML emails and all my templates use .cshtml extensions for this very reason. I don't have any particular reason to change it.

Comment: Alas, there might be a good reason to change this: Building MVC views using the csproj MvcBuildViews tag. The Nuget RazorEngine package supports custom operations not supported by the default Razor engine, so this breaks my MvcBuildViews. Ever fixed this?